# Call JNI exported method from C++

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, native

In my c++ there is a JNI exported method so that I can use it in my Java code:

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL
Java_com_wessel_QC_privateMethod();
```

But now I want to call that function from the C++ code. But how is that possible?

Comment: Can't you just call it as usual function?

Comment: unfortunately that is not possible

Comment: Why it is not possible? Linker missing symbol? Runtime errors?

Comment: Because I'm using a prebuild shared library. In the sample code a Java library calls the shared library with "public native int privateMethod()". So the library probably has a jni exported function, but I want to use that function within c++